# Retrieve previous file contents on ItemUpdated

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, spfile

I am writing an event receiver on a document library.

I need to get the previous version of the document, before the upload. `BeforeProperties` unfortunately does not give me the `SPFile`, only the columns. I suppose I can try and go through the document's versions, but that seems ugly, and also it would be nice to not have to have versioning turned on.

Am I missing something inside `properties`? Do I have to find the previous version? If I do have to find the previous version, what does that code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ItemUpdating** allows you to get the file before the upload/action has taken place. **ItemUpdated** requires you to go through version history.

In code you can get the previous version as follows:

```
SPFile file = ...;
SPFileVersion previousVersion = file.Versions[file.Versions.Count - 1];
```

Comment: How would I do it with ItemUpdating then? also, don't you mean `file.Versions[file.Versions.Count - 2]`? as -1 would get the last item in the collection, meaning the latest version?

Comment: I do mean -1 because file.Versions (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileVersionCollection) only contains previous versions. If you want the 'current' version that is just the SPFile reference of course.

Comment: In ItemUpdating you can use the SPFile reference to get the version that will be overwritten. It depends on your business scenario if you can actually do your logic in there already or not.

Comment: ah! i see... so in `ItemUpdating`, `properties.ListItem.File` is the old file, and in `ItemUpdated`, `properties.ListItem.File` is the new file... that's different from other stuff I've read, but does make sense with my testing. Thank you